# How to install clang on linux device?

Tags: c, linux

i tried using these codes as below

```
 ~ $ sudo apt-get install clang-3.5
```

and it showed something like this

```
[sudo] password for comp: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
clang-3.5 is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 167 not upgraded.
```

but when i try to use clang it shows something like this

```
~ $ clang
The program 'clang' can be found in the following packages:
 * clang-3.3
 * clang-3.4
 * clang-3.5
Try: sudo apt-get install <selected package>
```

please help .

Comment: While you try to install a compiler, which kind of makes it on-topic here on SO, the problem is more with the operating system and/or package manager, and so would fit better on either http://askubuntu.com/ (if you're using Ubuntu) or more generally on http://superuser.com/.

Answer (score 1):

Its called "clang-3.5" like it says
Try:

> $ clang-3.5

If you want to just type clang you can

> $ sudo ln -s /usr/bin/clang-3.5 /usr/bin/clang

Also on a side note you have updates available.
Also **stackoverflow is not the right forum** for this questions